# Put a dropdown in a innerHTML in getelementbyID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on a Javascript page which processes the insert, delete ,add row  in HTML table. I am writing the edit_row() function which changes the values in the row to the forms and when saves them through save_row() function through Ajax.
In the column named Platform there could only be four values - 1,2,3 and 4. I decided to use the dropdowns for it as it easily validate the input,so the user won't insert values other than 1 2 3 and 4. I've tried putting the HTML for drop-down inside the innerHTML, but it looks weird and I am wondering are there any other ways of putting dropdowns in JavaScript? 
Here is the code for edit_row():

```
function edit_row(id)
{
    var companyname=document.getElementById("name"+id).innerHTML;
    var destination=document.getElementById("destination"+id).innerHTML;
    var time=document.getElementById("time"+id).innerHTML;
    var platform=document.getElementById("destination"+id).innerHTML;
    var date=document.getElementById("date"+id).innerHTML;

    document.getElementById("name"+id).innerHTML="<input type='text' id='compname_text"+id+"' value='"+companyname+"'>";
    document.getElementById("destination"+id).innerHTML="<input type='text' id='age_text"+id+"' value='"+destination+"'>";
    document.getElementById("time"+id).innerHTML="<input type='time' id='time"+id+"' value='"+time+"'>";
    document.getElementById("platform"+id).innerHTML="<form id='platform"+id+"' value='"+platform+"'><select><option value = '12'> 1 </option ><option value = > 2</option></select>";
    document.getElementById("date"+id).innerHTML="<input type='date' id='date"+id+"' value='"+time+"'>";

    document.getElementById("edit_button"+id).style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("save_button"+id).style.display="block";
```

The HTML which should come with JS:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href = "style.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Departures table for workers </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="table" align="center">
    <div style = "background-color:#FFFFFF; padding:20px;"><b>Departures Table for workers</b></div>
    <table border="1" align="center" width="700">
        <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Train Company</th>
            <th>Destination</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Platform</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['id']?></td>
                <td id="name"><?php echo $row['Traincompany'] ?></td>
                <td id="destination"><?php echo $row['Destination']  ?></td>
                <td id="time"><?php echo $row['Time'] ?></td>
                <td id="platform"><?php echo $row['Platform'] ?></td>
                <td id="date"><?php echo $row['Date'] ?></td>
                <td>
                    <input type='button' class="edit_button" id="edit_button<?php echo $row['id'];?>" value="edit" onclick="edit_row('<?php echo $row['id'];?>');">
                    <input type='button' class="delete_button" id="delete_button<?php echo $row['id'];?>" value="delete" onclick="delete_row('<?php echo $row['id'];?>');">
                    <input type='button' class="save_button" id="save_button<?php echo $row['id'];?>" value="save" onclick="save_row('<?php echo $row['id'];?>');">
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endwhile ?>
        <tr id="new_row">
            <td>New ID will be given automatically</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="new_Traincompany" placeholder="Company name"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="new_Destination" placeholder="Destination"></td>
            <td><input type="time" id="new_time"></td>
            <td align="center">
                    <select name = "Platform">
                      <option value = '1'> 1 </option >
                      <option value = '2'> 2</option >
                      <option value = '3'> 3</option >
                      <option value = '4'> 4 </option >
                    </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="date" id="new_date" ></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Insert Row" onclick="insert_row();"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p class="message">Logout from user<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know my code might  be really primitive, so I would like to see the suggestions on how to improve it or another ways to edit the row by Javascript.

Comment: Well you seem to store thing in a variable and then repeat the query... Example: `companyname` contains `document.getElementById("name"+id).innerHTML` But then you use the query again rather than just accessing the variable... Can you include the relevant HTML to go with your javascript please and explain what problem you are experiencing... Being more specific than *"but I don't know how to correctly put it in the innerHTML"* Thank you.

Comment: So should I just put the innerHTML part in the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all as @NewToJS mentioned, you don't have to call document.getElementById().innerHTML once again as soon as you assigned these to dedicated variables. So the code could be simplified like this:

```
function edit_row(id)
{
    var companyname=document.getElementById("name"+id).innerHTML;
    var destination=document.getElementById("destination"+id).innerHTML;

    companyname="<input type='text' id='compname_text"+id+"' value='"+companyname+"'>";
    destination="<input type='text' id='age_text"+id+"' value='"+destination+"'>";
   ...
```

Then if you don't like to insert all the code into innerHTML you can write a dedicated function to create dropdown list and call it from your main function.

```
function insertDropdown (quantity) {
  var div = document.createElement('select');
  div.setAttribute("name", "platform");

  for (let i=0; i<quantity; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.setAttribute("value", i)
    option.innerHTML = "option " + i
    div.appendChild(option)
  }
  document.getElementById('dropdown-container').appendChild(div)
}
```

Make sure you assigned a proper id for the `<td>` where to insert the dropdown and called the function from your main function.

```js
function insertDropdown(quantity) {
  var div = document.createElement('select');
  div.setAttribute("name", "platform");

  for (let i=0; i<quantity; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.setAttribute("value", i)
    option.innerHTML = "option " + i
    div.appendChild(option)
  }
  document.getElementById('dropdown-container').appendChild(div)
}

insertDropdown(3)
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="dropdown-container"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: And how does this help.... You can't seriously expect people to accept this as a answer when you dump one line of javascript without explaining the use of this or how/why it should help/fix the problem at hand.

Comment: It works pretty much the same author just did with another inputs... Sorry, but I really can't see what needs to be explained here.

Comment: You could explain the difference and why the difference should fix the current problem, that would be the point of offering a solution so that the OP understands the reason for those changes and how/why it makes any difference to the current source code.

Comment: Sorry, seems like I didn't get the question the first time

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Should it be just `platform.inserDropdown(4);` ?

Comment: No. The function works independantly from DOM nodes or objects. Just call it from your `edit_row()` function as is - `insertDropdown(4)`